# How I fixed: Can't upload images using formData (Browser Compatibilty)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

Can't use FormData on iOS, but in all Desktop browsers including Safari work.

```js
$("#form").on('submit', function(e){

  let formData = new FormData(this);
  
  sendwithAjax(formData);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of problems with FormData due to this:

```js
$("#form").on('submit', function(e){

  let formData = new FormData(this);
  
  sendwithAjax(formData);
});
```

Most browsers support this. The variable 'this' or 'e.currentTarget' corresponds to the form which contain all the inputs. So we just do a formData of a form.

Well, when it came to mobile, iOS, to be more specific things didn't go well. The XHR requests just crashed.

This is how I fixed:

```js
var formData = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
 var element = form[i];

 if(element.type === "file" && element.files.length > 0){
  formData.append(element.name, element.files[0], element.files[0].name);
 } else if(element.type === "checkbox" && element.checked){
  formData.append(element.name, element.value);
 } else if(element.type !== "checkbox"){
  formData.append(element.name, element.value);
 }
  
}

sendWithAjax(formData)
```

The problem was the 'form' inside the FormData instance, so I put every element of the form manually and it worked.